# Entry point was not found on calling Dispose

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entrypointnotfoundexcept

I'm unit testing a piece of code that uses a nested using statement. I've changed it to a `using` statement in a `try/finally` block. When I try to call the `Dispose` method in the `finally` block I get an `EntryPointNotFoundException`. I've tried a lot of things but I'm not sure how to solve this problem. Here is my code:

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(message.FileContent);

try
{
    using (var sftpClient = this.GetSftpClientFromId(message.CustomerId))
    {
        return sftpClient.UploadFileAsync(memoryStream, message.FileName, true);
    }
}
finally
{
    memoryStream?.Dispose();
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Shouldn't you await the result?

Comment: have you tried to use another using block for the stream?

Comment: The code is not good, because after you do `return UploadFileAsync` everything is disposed (client, stream) but file is still uploading after that (I mean your upload Task is in progress when this happens). Though it should not throw EntryPointNotFoundException anyway... Some other exception - sure, but this one I doubt that.

Comment: @PatrickHofman No the surrounding function also returns a Task

Comment: @SebastianL yes , I have tried a nested using statement. It results in the same error

Comment: Still, you should await it.

Comment: The memory stream is disposed before it is used. If you wait for the upload to occur then it will work. FYI you don't really need to dispose a memory stream, Stream implements disposable, but all Dispose in memory stream does is render it useless.

Comment: @Evk Are you saying that I do not need to Dispose the memorystream because it is already disposed? Documentation said only the variable declared in the using is disposed. How would you change this code?

Comment: Well it was said multiple times - you need to await the result (easiest solution here). You start UploadFileAsync task but you don't wait for it to complete. Instead you return from method. return executes all using\finally blocks and so your stream and client are disposed **before** UploadFileAsync had a chance to complete.

Comment: Yes, you don't need to dispose the memory stream, it is just a wrapper around a byte array. Nothing bad will happen if you don't dispose it: the garbage collector will completely clean it up. However, as everyone has said the "right" way to fix this is to await the upload.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs.html#https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs.html,396b4b852ac5e9eb,references

Comment: Okay thanks for the help all! if someone makes an answer out of it I will accept it

Comment: I've got no idea why someone down-voted your question. It was well asked and you added the code snipped that demonstrated the problem. Some of the people on this site just baffle me.

Comment: The exception just does not have anything to do with the snippet.  If the Dispose() method would be missing then you'd get a MissingMethodException.  Well, you know that can't be it, it isn't missing.  EntryPointNotFoundException is a completely different kettle of fish, it does not know where to start running the program.  It probably has something to do with the unit test runner, we don't know anything about it.

Comment: @HansPassant The problem was resolved by adding the await statement, so it wasn't the unit test runner

Answer (score 2):

Just had this happen.

The problem ended up being:

**Short version:**

An assembly had a reference to an object that implemented IDisposable in a future version, but an old version was loaded at runtime.  So when it tried to call Dispose(), which didn't exist in the old version, it goes ummmmm EntryPointNotFoundException!

**Long version:**

- In version 1 of ThirdPartyComponent, Thing **did not** implement IDisposable.
- In version 2 of ThirdPartyComponent, Thing **did** implement IDisposable.
- ProjectA was built referencing version 2 of ThirdPartyComponent.  IDisposable is valid, and the "using" gets compiled just fine.
- ProjectA loaded version 1 of ThirdPartyComponent, and tries to call "Dispose()".  It freaks out because there is no "Dispose()" in version 1.  Of course, it **should** have loaded version 2, but sometimes the world isn't fair (in my case, a custom assembly loader messed up).